# Перенос программы с winxp на win server 2008

Tags: windows, delphi

Всем привет. Скоро нужно будет переносить программу с рабочей станции (winxp) на windows server 2008. Если у кого были такие истории, поделитесь плиз граблями и камнями подводными, что меня может ждать, от чего перестраховываться и т.п.

На всякий случай: используется кроме всего прочего SysUtils, Math, TcpServer, TcpClient, всякие операции с памятью (динамические массивы, указатели  и прочее).

Да, удовольствие недешевое запускать на время разработки, а дома возможности нет. Поэтому просто приветствуются общие советы.

Comment: Ну ворос сложный зависит то кучи параметров,но например у меня перенос крупного билингового проекта с ХР на 7 заняло 3 месяца (хотя там еше была смена кодировки на unicode) SysUtils и Math использовались TcpServer и TcpClient нет но использовалась работа с DLL.

Comment: А вот w7 у меня почти рядом имеется и я стараюсь параллельно разрабатывать, пока нарвался только на непонятку с Terminateprocess без админских прав. И да, у меня 2 dll )

Comment: Ну проект про который я говорю он по 98 начинался. ))
А паралельная разработка это вообше не благодарное дело, если конечно большой каманды нет под рукой )).
Я лично все под 7 делаю. А у ково ХР пусть сам думает как обновиться.

Да и пока единсвенные грабли в 2008 что наткнулся это программая регистрация и запуск сервиса 
(просто это мимолетная задача была както не пришлось углубляться)

Comment: <i>А у ково ХР пусть сам думает как обновиться.</i><p>
Это ублюдочность разработчиков. Сорри, не удержался. Писать нужно так, чтобы работало у всех. Пока еще пользователей ХР достаточно много. И их нужно иметь в виду. Причин множество - начиная от еще достаточно большого парка машин, на которых W7 будет тормозить (про комфортную работу можно забыть), вплоть до нежелания финансировать империю Зла (M$). Кстати, если программа работает корректно под wine - мой респект.

Comment: @gecube я сам злостный форточник и даже пофинансировать особо не прочь, другое дело - ХР привычнее, приятнее и при правильной настройке быстрее "голой" win7. Как перепилить win7 в такое, я не в курсе просто) Алсо я не поставлю домой ОС, под которой сходу не пашет fallout2)) А к проге - сознательно пишу на WinApi, это не софт на продажу, так что тесты под wine "может быть, когда-нибудь". А вообще с призывом соглашусь.
@Vahan Av я просто на критических этапах отсылаю прогу и мне говорят, где падает и с каким воплем =)

Comment: @Sh4dow, если прога написана под голый WinAPI и не использует каких-либо кривых фич кривых виндов, то априори под wine она должна работать без проблем.

Comment: "Это ублюдочность разработчиков" Жестоко по принято ))
Но всетаки посли многочисленных тестов я лично пршел к выводу что 7 как в скорости так и в стабильности намного провосходит ХР
а насчет "достаточно большого парка машин, на которых W7 будет тормозить" Я для пробы поставил 7 на 4пентиум с 512 МБ ОЗУ Работало лучше чем ХР единственное что требует это порядка 10 Г места.

И Я шас всем и везде рекомендую если форточки то 7ая )).

Comment: <i>Но всетаки посли многочисленных тестов я лично пришел к выводу что 7 как</i><p>
После многочисленных экспериментов, я пришел к выводу, что надо внедрятьт linux :-)

Comment: Ой только не холивар и только не здесь) У форточников тоже аргументов много) Мне полмесяца на линухе хватило, потом решил, что бессонные ночи лучше все-таки с девушкой проводить))) Собственно отчасти поэтому и delphi+winapi. Но тема не об этом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если программа не пишет, что попало в системные диры, то проблем особо быть не должно. 
(У меня приложение на delphi прекрасно работает на всей линейке win от 95 до vista (на семерке не пробовал) и с некоторыми косяками под wine (потеря фокуса некторыми окнами)).

Comment: А вайн со слэшами "\\" дружит? ЗЫ: у меня одно окошко только потому, что не влом в консили цикл while true do делать) Спасибо, ценно.

Comment: Дружит.

Answer (score 0):

дружит. для приложения wine выглядит как винда (если специально не ставить проверок).